# Odoo Priority Widget Not Show Every Options

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to the priority widget on my selection field. But priority widget not show the first option. I will start from the second option.

[image]

[image]

Is this a bug from Odoo source code or I need to write something else to make it work as I expected?

Comment: I think 0 star = [1], 1 star = [2], and 2 stars = [3]. Not sure though. I have never used it. You can just check the value of it.

Comment: No, starting with zero not working either

Comment: I mean selecting 0 star will give you the value of the first selection, selecting 1 star will give you the value of the second selection, and selecting 2 stars will give you the value of the third selection.

Comment: Interesting, I will play aroud with it

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo Widget priority :

- if you want 5 levels you must start from '0' to '5'
- if you want 4 levels you must start from '0' to '4'
- if you want 3 levels you must start from '0' to '3' and so on

So in your example you should add field as below

> priority = fields.selection([('0', 'Very Low'),('1', 'Low'),('2',
> 'Normal'),('3', 'High'), string = 'Priority']

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
priority = fields.Selection([(0, ''), (1, 'Low X'), (2, 'Normal Y'), (3, 'High Z')]
```